# Write a query to switch the ids for students who are next to each other? Here is the sample input

Tags: mysql, sql, database, plsql

1) Write a query to switch the ids for students who are next to each other? Here is the sample input.

```
+---------+---------+
|    id   | student |
+---------+---------+
|    1    | Abbot   |
|    2    | Doris   |
|    3    | Emerson |
|    4    | Green   |
|    5    | Jeames  |
+---------+---------+
```

For the sample input, the output is:

```
+---------+---------+
|    id   | student |
+---------+---------+
|    1    | Doris   |
|    2    | Abbot   |
|    3    | Green   |
|    4    | Emerson |
|    5    | Jeames  |
+---------+---------+
```

Note that if the total number of seats is odd, The id for the last one remains the same.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current attempt!

Comment: Will `id` values be continuous ?

Comment: This question seems better suited to Code Golf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ID's are ordered this will help you,

```
SELECT a.id,b.Name
 from
(SELECT [id],[Name]
  FROM [Table]
  where mod([id],2)=1) a
  inner join 
  (SELECT [id],[Name]
  FROM [Table]
  where mod([id],2)=0) b
  on a.id+1=b.id

  UNION

  select b.id,a.Name
 from
(SELECT [id],[Name]
  FROM [Table]
  where mod([id],2)=1) a
  inner join 
  (SELECT [id],[Name]
  FROM [Table]
  where mod([id],2)=0) b
  on a.id+1=b.id
```

Comment: This is not MySQL; nor PL/SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

**[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ndYw3aKm8tdwzJyDfpCfCn/0)**

```
select id,coalesce(bname,aname) as Name from
(
select A.id,A.name as aname,B.name as bname
from
(select id,name
from cte1 where id%2=1
)A left join 
(select id,name
from cte1 where id%2=0
)B on A.id+1=B.id

union all

select A.id,A.name,B.name
from
(select id,name
from cte1 where id%2=0
)A left join 
(select id,name
from cte1 where id%2=1
)B on A.id=B.id+1
)X order by id
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  Name
1   Doris
2   Abbot
3   Green
4   Emerson
5   Jeames
```

Comment: It's not MySQL or PL/SQL

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran, it's ANSI sql - so it'll work on oracle, mysql, sql server

Comment: I said that because your demo is for SQL Server, it's better if you can put a demo for MySQl

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran, yes - but it will work in any database

Comment: your demo wont work for MySQL since you have a table expression.

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran -  check here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kdf9iwaEPPz6kMpHqWhZkh/0

Comment: Your demo seems to be for something else

Comment: @Strawberry, thank you - mistakenly put it there , now updated it